# How to get nodes from Google Search?

Tags: search

I'm using CSE in my drupal website and due to some technique restrictions i couldn't use Solr search.

My news portal gives a " RELATED CONTENT " block to each article using tags similarity but i'm not very satisfied with the result.

I wonder if there's a way to integrate Google Search (like solr module does) to return back (in a view) a list of similar nodes by searching the title for example.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a content recommendation system. This isn't what Google CSE is built for and implementing the way you describe would likely result in poor results.

You're better off implementing one of Drupal's existing recommendation modules or some other 3rd party recommendation service (e.g. [OutBrain](http://www.outbrain.com/)).

Some of Drupal's recommendation modules include:

- **[Recommender API](https://www.drupal.org/project/recommender)**: Broad API that ties into other Drupal entities.
- **[Similar By Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/similarterms)**: Use similar taxonomy terms to find related content.
- **[Similar Entries](https://www.drupal.org/project/similar)**: Uses MySQL full text searching to find related content.

Comment: Similar by entries is that what i'm using actually but i don't like the results so much, and for some reasons i disabled search module so i can't use Similar entries module, i will test the Recommander API and see what it result , even my question is how to implement cse to get the result .